# Reading php code from database

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I want to save function in database. For example we have table function with attributes: function and function name. For saving function for time we would save it in data base:

`time_funtion(){ return time() } and "Time"`.

I have no idea how to execute this function after reading from DB is this even possible?

I could do this with files - read from database then write it in file, then include file and calling this function will work. Any other ideas?

Comment: seems like a misguided workaround for a misunderstood problem .. when answer is "use eval", you are asking the wrong question

Comment: possible duplicate of [String variable to execute PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577475/string-variable-to-execute-php-code)

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to try to explain in a few words why would you even consider implementing something so nasty and error-prone. Maybe we can suggest a workaround, that will enable you to write robust code, without having to rely on something so evil. Just imagine that somebody else comes after you to modify this code...

Comment: @Luka, @tereško  is correct. Use `eval` function and pass your code as parameter to it.

Comment: @Imdad , what is complete opposite of what i meant

Comment: Its an idea for IA, and thank you for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
    eval("your PHP code here")

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this but you could use `eval()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eval()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) for this. But be careful what you save into your db. There are just a few problems where this is a useful approach. In 99% you don't need this and it's lacking security, because you are executing unkown code, which is not what you want.