# Fetching PHP code from table field in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a table `notifications` where I have a field `notification` which has value:

`<?php echo '.$user['name'][0].' ?>, you are <?php echo popularity(); ?>% popular today.`

The output is: `, you are % popular today.`

It is ignoring the PHP here. I don't understand why.

Expected output is `Shubham, you are 35% popular today.`

Under network in inspect element the response tab with raw data shows this:

```
<div class="notiText">
  <?php echo $user['name'][0]; ?> you are <?php echo popularity(); ?>% popular today.
</div>
```

What's the issue here? Why does the script does not load PHP tags from the database?

**EDIT**

I have tried using `eval()` from here [Reading php code from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702147/reading-php-code-from-database). However, I have to do that into the database and not in code. The new output has this `eval(), you are eval()% popular today.`. Still not reading.

Note: I cannot use `eval()` into the coding. This has to be dynamic and from database. Therefore, anyone who is thinking of suggesting `eval()` I need an alternative or a workaround to the situation with `eval()` and database.

**UPDATE**

Here is the sample code:

processes/notifications.php

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT notification FROM notifications");
$stmt-> execute();

$html = "<div class='notifications'>";
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$f['notification'].'</a>';
}
$html .= "</div>";
echo $html;
```

Jquery

```
$(".notificationsBell").on("click", function(e){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processes/notifications.php",
    data: "all",
    success: function(data){
      $(".loadNotifications").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="loadNotifications"></div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Okay so the following code is giving me the proper output.

```
$str = ''.$user['name'][0].', you are '.popularity().'% popular today.';

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;
```

Output: `Shubham Jha, you are 100% popular today.`

Now, how do I insert that string (the value of `$str`) into the database? In the table field what should be the format so that it gets recognized and echoed correctly. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
'.$user['name'][0].', you are '.popularity().'% popular today.
```

Returns this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in E:\xampp\htdocs\newchat\processes\notifications.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: You should show the php code generating the above code. However, you need to be mindful that whatever you retrieve from a database will be data and not code.

Comment: Therefore, if the data within the database is a php code, then it must be run through the eval() function to execute it, there is no way around this limitation. I frankly do not understand why you cannot use eval() (well, why you need to store php code in the database in the first place...). Pls provide more context!

Comment: @Shadow I have updated the question. I have provided everything necessary from PHP code to AJAX to HTML. Please have a look.

Comment: What and where is echo popularity();?? and how exactly are you echoing it?! you can echo a variable, the function returns values or print within the function and just call it without echo.

Comment: you should $something = popularity(); and then echo $something; also is something a string? if returned data is not a string you cannot echo it... print_r($something);

Comment: @Shlomtzion It's a function in my `functions.php` that returns an integer and don't worry it's being accessed well. Just not being echoed. Also, using `return` in that function.

Comment: @Shlomtzion also, forget about `popularity()` for a minute. What about `$user['name'][0]` ? Even that isn't being echoed in the page from the database. They both echo well when used directly. Problem is when fetched from the database.

Comment: @RelaxingMusic Where is $user coming from ?! I see you create $html is that where you get the $user data? where is $user populated?

Comment: @RelaxingMusic are you creating anywhere $user['name'][] = $f['name'];  <- shouldn't this be in the the while loop of the select?!

Comment: It's a bit confusing but I believe you are expecting things that happen after to occur before... :) - You need to clarify , when is the sql select being done, when is the $user variable populated and when/where are you displaying the "notiText" div...

Comment: Also I would like to point out that if $user['name'][0] is known not from the sql... shouldn't it be in the SELECT ???? WHERE name = {$user['name'][0]} .. or something?!

Comment: `$user` is derived from a function in `functions.php`. They all work well when coded normally. Should be working here as well. Those aren't the issue. I think I was not able to use `eval()` properly.

Comment: I have another update where I have figured out something. Please look at UPDATE 2 in the question.

Comment: @Shlomtzion got the answer by RedStar Entertainment :)

Comment: @Shadow got the answer by RedStar Entertainment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  // STORE IN SIMPLE VARIABLES 
  $name = $user['name'][0];
  $popularity = popularity();

  $notiText = $f['notification'];
  eval("\$notiText = \"$notiText\";");

  $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$notiText.'</a>';
}
```

In the database use these simple variable names and avoid using quotes.

`$name, you are $popularity% popular today.`

Comment: Perfect.... Thanks :)