# php code into variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I want to insert a PHP code into a variable.

I want to replace "Some text" with a PHP code.

I found some examples on the internet, but when I try to run my script it isn't working.

This is my current script:
`$purchaseID = "Some text";`

I want to change "Some text" with the following code:

```
<?php
  echo date('y/m/d');
  echo "O";
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("db", $link); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $link);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);echo "$num_rows"+1;
?>
```

I have tried:

```
$purchaseID = <<<END
echo date('y/m/d');
echo "O"; 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("db", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows"+1;
END;
```

When I run this I get a error.

How can I fix this and replace "Some text" with the PHP code?

Comment: Why do you want to have "some code into a variable", what you expect is to have `$purchaseID: "2016/06/24O5"` (if $num_rows = 4) is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to have!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the *heredoc* syntax, that interpolates variables. You might want the *herenow* syntax without interpolation:

```
$purchaseID = <<<'END'
    echo $variable;
END;

// $purchaseID == "echo $variable;"
```

Enclose the delimiter into single qoutes. Interpolation is *not* done in this case. To execute the code, you have to use `eval($purchaseID);`. Be aware, that `eval` has a dangerous potential when relying on external data.

Comment: I get a error message. When I vardump $purchaseID ill get the right string.

When I vardump $requestTransaction ($purchaseID is a part of this) I get: "Transaction.purchaseId does not match format."

Comment: You should create a new question targeting the problem to form a proper transaction format. Provide all the necessary code with the new question. You can simplify the example code by hardcoding the expected value into `$purchaseID`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well your need, you just need to concatenate the different part of the string:

```
$purchaseID = date('y/m/d');
$purchaseID .= "O"; 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("db", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$purchaseID .= $num_rows + 1;
```

You will get (considering `$num_rows` to be 4)

> 2016/06/24O5

Do you really need the heredoc syntax here?

Comment: I get a error message. When I vardump $purchaseID ill get the right string.

When I vardump $requestTransaction ($purchaseID is a part of this) I get: "Transaction.purchaseId does not match format."

Comment: Edit your question to explain what is `$requestTransaction` and what do you mean by `$purchaseID` *is part of this*. But this is another problem right? Does your initial problem is fixed?

Comment: I dont know if my problem is fixed. The script is still not working by some reason. It is also possible that the script is not working because the solution I tried is not working

Comment: We can't really help you since we don't know nothing about `$requestTransaction`

Comment: No "snake questions" please. Let new aspects like `$requestTransaction` go into a completely new question.

Answer (score 0):

try but i don't recommend you  [eval](http://php.net/eval)

There are some side effects using eval() [refer and learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577475/string-variable-to-execute-php-code)

```
<?php


$time =  '<?php echo time(); ?>'; 

eval('?>'.$time.'<?php;');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to escape the variables, like this:

```
$purchaseID = <<<END
echo date('y/m/d');
echo "O"; 
\$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("db", \$link);
\$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", \$link);
\$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(\$result);
echo "\$num_rows"+1;
END;
```

That's it!

Cheers!